# How to make the profile picture of Twitter bigger (NodeJs, Ejs and passport)

Tags: node.js, twitter, size, passport.js

Some background info: I am working with node.js, express framework, mongo and passport-twitter

I am able to successfully login in with Twitter and store info like id, username, profile pic to db (mongo). I am able to pass it along to my view with ejs but it shows the image pretty small.

I read on the Twitter developer page that you can pass along alternate sizes for the picture

My question is how to do this with the passport.js syntax, this is the code that i have for saving the image to my db:

```
 newUser.twitter.profilePic  = profile.photos[0].value;
```

the output is the following: http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/568828382079483905/FuEj1pBH_normal.png

i tried this bit of code:

```
newUser.twitter.profilePic  = profile._json.profile_image_url.replace('_original','');
```

but it still saves the image to my db as follow -> http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/568828382079483905/FuEj1pBH_normal.png

So basically what i am asking is how to make the twitter picture bigger. How to pass on the right size with passport syntax

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 7):

Just remove **_normal** like following url :-

http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/568828382079483905/FuEj1pBH.png

Thanks

Comment: I can't change the url of the photo because it saves directly into my db. so i have to change it when saving it to my userSchema. Thus the question of how to best do this with the passport.js syntax.